# JASIG CAS - Allow only one session per user account

Tags: spring, spring-security, single-sign-on, cas

We have achieved "Single Sign On" in our application with help of JASIG CAS as a authentication server.

Now we need to have a setup in which only one session/ticket per user can be created in CAS.

If the user tries to log in from other system/browser, CAS shall invalidate the current ticket for the user and logout him/her from previous session/browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found a Solution to the problem my self. Hope it will help others.

Jasig Cas itself uses a in memory map to keep a track of the ticket allotted for the users. I am using a similar approach to achieve the requirement :-

In Order to achieve the functionality, some additional functionalities were added to project. The changes are listed below:-

1. Implementation of "SingleSesionTicketRegistry" class which maintains the session tickets in a map as a default behavior, but if there is already a ticket for a user in the map, then the registry will invalidate the previous session.
2. Modification of Cas configuration to use a Mysql Database for authentication where password is MD5 Hashed.
3. Modification of Cas configuration to use the custom Ticket Registry instead of Default one.

Below are configuration changes which has to be done in project :- 1. src/main/resources/application.properties

```
#Toggle the feature if Single Session.
is.single.sesion.per.user=true

#MySQL query to check the authentication.
user.authentication.sql=select password from user where email=? and is_active=1
```

/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/ticketRegistry.xml

```
<!--Comment the default ticket regitry. -->
<!-- <bean id="ticketRegistry" class="org.jasig.cas.ticket.registry.DefaultTicketRegistry" />  -->

<!--Add the custom ticket regitry. -->
<bean id="ticketRegistry" class="com.naval.cas.SingleSesionTicketRegistry"  
p:isSingleSesionPerUser="${is.single.sesion.per.user}"
p:logoutManager-ref="logoutManager"/>
```

/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deployerConfigContext.xml

```
<!--Add the Following code block -->
<bean id="passwordEncoder"
  class="org.jasig.cas.authentication.handler.DefaultPasswordEncoder"
  c:encodingAlgorithm="MD5"
  p:characterEncoding="UTF-8" />

<bean id="primaryAuthenticationHandler"
  class="org.jasig.cas.adaptors.jdbc.QueryDatabaseAuthenticationHandler"
  p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
  p:passwordEncoder-ref="passwordEncoder"
  p:sql="${user.authentication.sql}" />
```

The Single Session Ticket Registry Class can be found at the github repo below.

https://github.com/navalgandhi1989/jasig-cas-single-session/blob/master/src/main/java/com/naval/cas/SingleSesionTicketRegistry.java